# Disable django 2.0 admin responsive behavior

Tags: django, django-admin, responsive

This behaviour is not friendly for me and my team, we need a full view.

Is there a way to disable this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/responsive.css" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put somewhere: `{% block responsive %}{% endblock %}`

In custom `templates/admin/base_site.html`